# Can I run JavaScript in the browser without HTML? Why/Why Not?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, browser

I'm new to web development and I'm wondering if it's possible to run a JavaScript file in the browser **without** using HTML and a `<script>` tag, and without using a framework.

I'm only asking because in React (using `create-react-app`), the `index.js` file just runs in the browser without any HTML file loading it in. **How is this possible?**

Any links/articles/insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: HTML is added by the browser when missing. Also, CRA does use an index.html file. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/folder-structure

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yeah but there's no script tab inside their index.html, so I don't see what is running the index.js file. Yet it still runs in the browser

Comment: @WillWillington The create-react-app node server inject it on the server side before it reaches the browser. Its a bit of magic, but by the time HTML reaches the browser, its there.

Comment: Check the build output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't possible -- excluding the [REPL](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/) terminal in the browser dev tools.

`create-react-app` *does* use HTML. The `create-react-app` server dynamically injects the script tag into the HTML thats in your project in `public/index.html`. You can see this if you use the browser dev tools to inspect the DOM.

Comment: Oh! I can't believe I didn't notice that in the dev tools. Thank you, this explanation makes a lot of sense now. I'll accept this answer when the site allows me to